# Do $0$ terms count as a term in Maclaurin expansions?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have a question which basically asks to find

$$\int_a^b \ln(1+\sqrt x) \,dx$$

using the **first five terms** of the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$. There are limits to the question and my solutions are correct (with respect to the number of terms used) however I'm unsure if I've actually used enough terms of the expansion.

So,

$$\ln(1+x) = \frac{0}{0!}x^0 + \frac{1}{1!}x -\frac{1}{2!}x^2 +\frac{2}{3!}x^3 - \frac{6}{4!}x^4 + ...$$

Now, I thought that this would be the first **five** terms of the Maclaurin series, however, when the series is evaluated, it gives:

$$\ln(1+x) = 0 + x -\frac{1}{2}x^2 +\frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^4 + ...$$

which would be written as: $$\ln(1+x) =x -\frac{1}{2}x^2 +\frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^4 + ...$$

which is now **four** terms.

So if I let $ f(x)=\ln(1+x) $, when I evaluate my integral $\int_a^b \ln(1+\sqrt x) \,dx = \int_a^b f( \sqrt x)dx$, does this mean I'm only really approximating the integral with 4 terms? Basically, what I'm trying to illustrate is if the $0$ counts as a term anymore or would I have to integrate the function using $$f(x) =x -\frac{1}{2}x^2 +\frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^4 + \frac{1}{5}x^5 + ...$$

so that I'm now using **five** terms to approximate the integral asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $0$ does count as a term, and you are using five terms of the Maclaurin series, when approximating the integral. That the first term is $0$ simply means that the best constant approximation to the function $\ln(1+x)$ at $x=0$ is equal to $0$. You use this constant in all subsequent higher order approximations, i.e. the best first order approximation is $0+x$, and so forth.

You can also make the number of terms visible by considering the error term:

$$\ln(1+x) =x -\frac{1}{2}x^2 +\frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^4 + O(x^5).$$

You are dealing with a fifth order error term in your approximation, which signifies that you have five terms in your Maclaurin expansion.

Comment: So integrating $x -\frac{1}{2}x^2 +\frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^4$ with my limits - as I have originally done - would be sufficient as an estimate with 5 terms? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Leo yes, agreed. :)

Comment: Oh, I see! The $0$ is still there but when integrated gives $0x$ which is just equal to $0$. Thank you!